# How to Add Link preview to app store connect?

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

It is my first tile that I try to send my app to app store review.
but i have received this message from apple team
"Provide a link to the video in the App Review Information section of your app’s page in App Store Connect and reply to this message. You can use a screen recorder to capture footage of your app in use. Note that if your app can only be reviewed with a demo video, you’ll need to provide an updated demo video for every app submission."
it is clear that i need to add a video preview of my app.
But i still confident how to provide this link?
And how to add this video i see in app store connect the field attachment it is the corresponding field?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4yVXm.png)

Answer (score 0):

Upload the video to YouTube (or any hosting of your preference) as unlisted and share the link in the app review notes.

Did that with one of my apps and the review went smoothly.